# how to get instance of running accessibility service in android

Tags: android, android-service, accessibilityservice, android-service-binding

I want to take a accessibility service instance and call there method in
Activity.
I tried taking

`AccessibilityService as = new AccessibilityService ()`

`as.doSomething()`

but this works for first time only.

Comment: First of all, you cannot instantiate `AccessibilityService`, as it is `abstract`. You need to create your own class that `extends AccessibilityService`. Secondly, you absolute positively cannot instantiate an Android `Service` using the `new` keyword. Services are Android framework components and they can only be instantiated by the Android framework directly. 
The framework instantiates the `Service` and sets up the `Context` and other behind-the-scenes` data structures that are necessary to ensure that the `Service` gets the appropriate lifecycle callbacks, etc.

Comment: What method are you trying to call? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: method to Find Scrollable node on current screen through AccessibilityService

Comment: You need to read about how to create an `AccessibilityService`. This isn't how you do that.